# Adonis: Tables are not populating while trying to use the seed command with comma separated --files

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, heroku, adonis.js

I am trying to seed multiple files at the same time in the local system as well as in the Heroku portal for hosting the application using the command:
adonis seed --files=Seeder1.js,Seeder2.js,CommonSeeder.js --force
It prompts that the database has seeded. However, there isn't any data in the 3 tables after running the command.

It gets populated if I run the seed commands separately as follows but the issue with that is one seeding command resets the data seeded by the other command:

```
adonis seed --files=Seeder1.js
adonis seed --files=Seeder2.js
adonis seed --files=CommonSeeder.js
```

Is there a workaround for seeding multiple files in one command?

Answer (score 1):

you need to run files separated by comma

`adonis seed --files="Seeder1.js,Seeder2.js,CommonSeeder.js"`

in server you need to put --force like this:

`adonis seed --files="Seeder1.js,Seeder2.js,CommonSeeder.js" --force`

for more info check [adonisjs doc](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/seeds-and-factories#_faqs)